# Error Message in in mscorlib.dll. Why?

Tags: c#, matlab, dll

I get this error message:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

but my program works correctly. My output is a matlab plot. But i dont want this error message.

**My c# Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {  
            MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();
            matlab.Execute(@"cd S:\temp_ausleeren\matlab1_function_csharp");// Funktion die exekutiert werden soll
            object result = null;
            string var1 = "MatlabExport_SigX_Spectr.txt";
            // Call the MATLAB function 
            matlab.Feval("matlab1_function_csharp", 1, out result, var1);
            object[] res = result as object[];
            Console.WriteLine(res[0]);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: " But i dont want this error message."  What error message?  What is the actual *message* associated with the error?  We can't help you without that important piece of information.

Comment: sorry for my bad english... if i compile my code this window appears -> **An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll** is this not a error message? Then i click continue and the my output window appears (with diagrams)

Comment: No, thats not the error message.  I'm talking about the value of the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException.Message` property.

Comment: **'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\z003dukj\Documents\Arbeitsverzeichnis_M\CSharp_Schnittstelle\ConsoleApplication2\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication2.exe'. Symbols loaded.**

Comment: **A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurredin mscorlib.dll
An unhandled exception oftype 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols.Module is optimized and the debugger option Just My Code' isenabled.
The program '[12228] ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0)**

Comment: That's not what I'm talking about...have you set the debugger to break on exceptions so you can observe the actual exception object?

Comment: matlab.Feval("matlab1_function_csharp", 1, out result, var1); **in this row**

Comment: No, that's not helpful.  I'm sorry, but you need to do what I've suggested and debug the code with break on exception turned on.  Then look at the exception variable (in the locals window) when the exception occurs.

Comment: @roy.ap   HResult -2147467259 , -  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException] {""} System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException